# MySQL NTILE Bucket Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a percentile column with 10 buckets using:

```
SELECT *, NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY returns) AS 'percentile' FROM db.table1;
```

I wnat to isolate one bucket like `SELECT * FROM db.table1 WHERE percentile = 10` but I get "percentile" column doesn't exists.

Is there a way to use NTILE and then select just one bucket simultaneously?
(New to mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT *, NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY returns) AS percentile
      FROM db.table1
     ) t1
WHERE percentile = 1;
```

This is true of any alias defined in the `FROM` clause.

You can also use MySQL's extension of the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT *, NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY returns) AS percentile
FROM db.table1
HAVING percentile = 1;
```